# When calling EntityManager.flush() will it flush the second cache too?

Tags: java, jpa

When calling EntityManager.flush(), will it flush the second level cache too? I tried Googling and I also tried flushing it and it seems like it does, but it would be good to have it confirmed.

***Edit: Now it does not seem like it flush the second level cache.***

Answer (score 1):

JPA has no notion of a second-level cache (it isn't part of the spec). So the behavior of the second-level cache depends entirely upon the JPA provider. What are you using Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA?

Update: I stand partially corrected, JPA 2.0 introduces a few options to control second-level cache usage (like [@Cachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cacheable.html))

Comment: While looking for something about caching in JPA I found a few good links on second level caching - hopefully they will be of your help too -  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjio.html

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/f5/bb247575004294831c900556ca62ae/frameset.htm

Answer (score 0):

The L2 cache ought (by default, in any sensible JPA implementation) to be updated at commit **not** flush, but this is not mandated in the JPA2 spec, so you're down to implementation specifics. DataNucleus certainly only updates it at commit. If an L2 cache was updated at flush, and then those objects changes rolled back, this leads to potential invalid/non-persistent data being read. Some may allow that as an option.

Comment: Does not seem to flush the second level cache in EclipseLink then.